# shell script to convert date to hex format

Tags: shell, date, formatting, hex

I have a tool which requires the time in hex format.

Suppose if `date -d "Thu Sep 15 09:13:05 UTC 2011" +%s -u` gives the time in seconds as `1316077985`, the hex value of `1316077985` which is `4E71C1A1` should be found and it should be given as input to the tool as

`/usr/bin/mytool 0xA1 0xC1 0x71 0x4E`.

How can do this in shell script if the time in seconds is available as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
hex=$(printf '%X' 1316077985)
/usr/bin/mytool  0x${hex:6:2} 0x${hex:4:2} 0x${hex:2:2} 0x${hex:0:2}
```

Comment: Thanks. Inorder to tell the tool that it is hex, shouldn't it be like `/usr/bin/mytool 0x${hex:6:2} 0x${hex:4:2} 0x${hex:2:2} 0x${hex:0:2|`

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but it is perl, not shell:

```
fg@erwin ~/src/json-schema-validator $ date +%s | perl -e 'my $num = <STDIN>; my @hex; while ($num) { push @hex, sprintf("0x%02x", $num & 0xff); $num >>= 8; } print join(", ", reverse @hex) . "\n"'
0x4e, 0xe9, 0xec, 0x88
```